# Cloudflare and Azure integration

Tags: azure, dns, cloudflare

I have an Azure web app service that I'm trying to use cloudflare to point to using a custom domain. I've following similar process to this https://www.petermorlion.com/setting-up-custom-domains-in-azure-with-cloudflare/

I registered the domain with Go Daddy 2 days ago and amended the name servers. Using online tools it's correctly going through cloudflare. However, it still comes up with GoDaddy default page even though the A record is pointing to the Azure web app service IP address.

I'm not sure if I've missing something or just being impatient.

Appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have finished pointing your domain to the Cloudflare nameservers. Then you can [map your custom domain DNS records to Azure app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain).

First of all, you need to ensure that the web app's App Service plan must be a **paid tier** (Shared, Basic, Standard, Premium or Consumption for Azure Functions). Then, you can use either a `CNAME` record or an `A` record to map a custom DNS name to App Service.

**Create `CNAME` record**

> Add a CNAME record to map a subdomain to the app's default domain name
>   (.azurewebsites.net, where  is the name of your
>   app).
>
> For the `www.contoso.com` domain example, add a CNAME record that maps
>   the name `www` to `<app_name>.azurewebsites.net`.

**Create `A` record**

> To map an `A` record to an app, App Service requires two DNS records:
>
> An `A` record to map to the app's IP address. A `TXT` record to map to the
>   app's default domain name `<app_name>.azurewebsites.net`. App Service
>   uses this record only at configuration time, to verify that you own
>   the custom domain. After your custom domain is validated and
>   configured in App Service, you can delete this `TXT` record.

After you added the relative records, you can select **Add custom domain** of the app service settings. Verify that your domain resolves to your app's IP address using [WhatsmyDNS.net](https://www.whatsmydns.net/). You may wait for an amount of time. If the browser has not effected on the new custom domain, you can Clear the cache and test DNS resolution again. On a Windows machine, you clear the cache with `ipconfig /flushdns`.

Let me know if this works or show your records(hiding sensitive data) for further help.